# Counter variable does not increment inside do while loop

Tags: powershell, logic

I'm learning PowerShell in school and trying to understand why this is not working:

```
$y = 1
do {
    $count = 1
    echo $count
    Start-Sleep 1
    $count++
}
while ($y -eq 1)

echo "Finished"
```

The output of this script is:
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    ...

What is the problem here? I would expect the count to increase.

Comment: `$count = 1` ... you reset the count in every single loop run.  ;-) .. you have to initialize this outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is very simple.  Inside your while loop, you are resetting $count = 1, on every loop.  As a result, you need to declare $count outside of the while loop and then let it increment inside the loop.

```
$y = 1;
$count = 1;
do {
    echo $count;
    $count++;
}
while (condition)
echo "Finished";
```

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers, you reset the counter in every loop. You need to create this outside the loop as you did with the $y variable. Also, try not to use double quotes when single quotes would suffice :)

```
$y = 1
$count = 1
do{
    echo $count
    Start-Sleep -s 1
    $count++
}while ($y -eq 1)
echo 'Finished'
```